How to set input format of DatePipe
I want to just display month and year i.e. 09/24.
Now, I am receiving list of bills that are generated in last 3 months through an API where bill date format is 'dd-mm-yyyy'.
billDataList = [
                 {'id' = 101, 'bill_date': '17-08-2024'},
                 {'id' = 102, 'bill_date': '02-08-2024'},
                 {'id' = 103, 'bill_date': '26-09-2024'}  
               ]

In html template, list is on loop to display the id and date
<ng-container *ngFor="let bill of billDataList>
   <div class="bill-row-small">
      <span>{{bill['id']: {{bill['bill_date'] | date:'MM/yy'}}</span>
   </div>
</ng-container>

But it throws error:

InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "28-09-2024" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'

This is may be because bydefault DatePipe takes format as 'medium' i.e. 'MMM d, y, h:mm:ss a'.
How to set input format of date as 'dd-mm-yyyy'

According to the docs, Angular expects a Date object, a number (milliseconds since UTC epoch), or an ISO string as input. "28-09-2024" is none of that.

This makes perfect sense, because otherwise Angular would need to guess the date format. For example when passing 02-08-2024, is it the second August or the eight February? To avoid any ambiguities, Angular forces you to pass a proper input.

Completely agree with you, but then on receiving response from API, I will have to iterate through the list in typescript, and then pass to HTML template. So is there a way to transform the string value to expected format in template itself?

Also, it works fine if date is below 12 i.e.  10th sept 2024 ('10-09-2024'). As it takes '10' as month

Angular's DatePipe expects a Date object, a number (milliseconds since UTC epoch), or an ISO string as input, that's the reason why inputs like "28-09-2024" lead to errors. This is to avoid ambiguities, for example, 02-08-2024 could either mean August 2nd or February 8th. You can transform your date string to a Date object with a custom pipe, before passing it to the date pipe:
@Pipe({
  name: 'stringToDate',
  standalone: true,
})
export class StringToDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): Date {
    const [day, month, year] = value.split('-');
    return new Date(+year, month - 1, +day);
  }
}

And use it like the following:
<span>{{bill['id']: {{bill['bill_date'] | stringToDate | date:'MM/yy'}}</span>


use + to convert to number: return new Date(+year, +month - 1, +day);

As mentioned in one of the comments, the DataPipe does accept ISO string, but the string you are passing is not a valid one. Notice that the DatePipe documentation links out to the web standards for valid ISO strings. The closest matching format to the string you currently have would be YYY-MM-DD:
Complete date:
      YYYY-MM-DD (eg 1997-07-16)

therefore, updating your code to the following should fix the error:
billDataList = [
                 {'id' = 101, 'bill_date': '2024-08-17'},
                 {'id' = 102, 'bill_date': '2024-08-02'},
                 {'id' = 103, 'bill_date': '2024-09-26'}  
               ]

